# Delete the repeated data in ModelChoiceField from the form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have this code `forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ModelClass.objects.all())`, but it shows all the values, besides the repeated, is there a way to delete the repeated data from the ModelChoiceFiel in the form but not in the model?

**Models.py**

```
class SchoolYear(models.Model):
    number=models.IntegerField() 

class Year(models.Model):
    year=models.IntegerField()


class Course(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    year = models.ForeignKey(year, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    schoolYear= models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class InfoForm(forms.Form):
     course=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Course.objects.all())
```

Comment: this is very up to your application, why is there repeated data in your database to begin with? what are the boundaries in which data is not repeated? etc.

Comment: the queryset comes from a single model, is there a way to have repeated values? `exclude`, `filter` from **django** and   `sorted`, `chain` are available to sort the queryset

Comment: The ModelClass have two foreign key and an integer, for example, is the model for a school course , it have the name of the course (repeated data), the school grade(foreingKey), and the year(foreing key), i onlu want to show the name of the course in the  ModelChoiceField without the user  see it duplicated

Comment: Show your models then. it'll be easier to help you

Comment: If I got it right, I realize that the `type` for course name is CharField which will cause repeated values... a better way to do it is to have a new Model `CourseName` that will receive all the course names. School Course, will have instead, the `course_name` field ForeignKey to the new model `CourseName` .... In your forms, you will need to just import the New Model `CourseName` as queryset for the forms.field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can proceed that way, you will have a queryset with all the course names withoud repeated values, inconvenient is it's not a quesryset of instance itself.

```
Course.objects.values_list('name',flat=True).distinct()
```

Other way, if you want to have the list of course instance:

```
courses_list = []
for name in Course.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).distinct():
    courses_list.append(Course.objects.filter(pk__in=Course.objects.filter(name=name).values_list('id', flat=True)).first())
```